# Is a GUI extension the proper way to capture information from our SSO system?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, sso

My organisation have Single Sign On authentication service in place for all organisational applications. Whenever a user hits Tridion CME, they get authenticated automatically with this service and we directly get the Tridion CME dashboard loaded.

Now I want to capture some information from this service through a HTTP header and some information from Tridion core to insert it in the custom database. For this we are  planning to execute a database stored procedure when Tridion dashboard get loaded. It looks that GUI extension is a way for this.

Could somebody suggest/correct me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could possibly do this via GUI extension, but note that a user doesn't always sees the dashboard when he or she logs in. If they use a url pointing to some structure group or folder, the user will bypass the dashboard, and immediately go to a specific view.
Also, the user can connect via Experience Manager or a core service client,... In some cases, your GUI extension will be triggered, but in other cases it won't.

It seems more appropriate to use the event system for this.

Mihai Cădariu wrote an interesting blog post on how to achieve something similar to what you want :
http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/capturing-users-last-login-date-into.html

In this example, he writes some data to the Application Data repository, but you could put any code you want there, such as connecting to your database, and inserting some data.

Comment: Thanks Harald for answering. I can not go with Event System because of the reason that SSO service provider will provide some information in http respose header For this we have to decide a Tridion URL(e.g. Dashboard URL). SO i want to extend the GUI of Tridion dashboard. Is it fine ? please correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: In that case, if you have to read the http headers, you should have the following options: 1) a GUI extension. 2) a custom page set as default starting page, which is an aspx page that writes all your logs to DB. 3) in the link i placed in my answer, there is also a reference to a http module. You could also create a .NET http module, and add this to your tridion setup by adding it to the Tridion config. This Httpmodule also has full access to all http headers

Answer (score 2):

I would use a iis module for this. As the information you are trying to capture is not dependent on tridion and in this way you are not building any dependency on that module. You would be able to reuse that module in other application as well to get the same functionality.